# With GKE's config-connector, create a service account and import it's key into kubernetes

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gcp-config-connector

I'm trying to use GKE's `config-connector` to create a service account (easy), and to create a service account key (also easy).
However, is there a way to also get that service account key imported into the cluster as kubernetes secret?

It feels like a perfectly IaaC setup with some decent privacy regarding the key. Declare service account, declare service account key, declare service account key is stored in *this* cluster's namespace, as *this* secret with *this* name. The actual service account key is never exposed to any users.

However, I can't seem to find an OOTB way with config connector.
Is this something anybody else has looked at?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, using ACM's [Config Connector](https://cloud.google.com/anthos-config-management/docs/config-sync-overview#rbac_permissions), you could certainly configure a K8s secret  using your SA key.

The other alternative may be to use [Workload Identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity) and associate a namespace with a Service Account.

Both of these options will give your workloads the ability to use the permissions granted via the Service Account.

Will either of these meet your requirements?  If so, please mark this as an answer.  Thanks!

Comment: hi!
but that's different from GKE's config-connector right...? looking through it, I don't see anything that I can actually leverage for an existing GKE cluster...

Comment: oh, and I need more granular service accounts than namespace level.